# Agile Toolkit "filestore"

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

Hi i am trying to implement the filestore for a prototype project, an online policy register.  I was following the Jobeet tutorial and have also looked at the doc/filestore page on agiletoolkit.com and the tutorial video on your youtube site, but I am unable to get it working.  Currently I am getting the following error when i access the fileadmin page

> PathFinder_Exception
>
> Unable to include SQL\Relation.php

my project is on github [HERE](https://github.com/Roxout/polyreg)

apologies if I am being silly but I'm new to agile.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Roxout/polyreg/blob/master/.gitignore#L102

This line in .gitignore file contains "sql". It have prevented atk4/lib/SQL/* from being added to the repository. Remove the line, and re-add the folder.

Next steps are to import https://github.com/Roxout/polyreg/blob/master/atk4-addons/misc/docs/filestore.001.sql and create page extending filestore\Page_FileAdmin.

Here is screencast about filestore, if you get stuck:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5dmAnvri1I&list=PL7CBF92AB03A1CA3B&index=9

Comment: Hi and thanks Romans, after i added the SQL folder the page loaded but would still not upload the  file, well the file uploaded but did not enter the information in the DB similar to the  symtoms described [HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/agile-toolkit-devel/AUNAjr2w_mY). The answer was to enable php_fileinfo, ive looked at the script, it was not showing me the  ''You have to enable php_fileinfo extension of PHP'' exception.

Comment: To @Roxout: So you're saying that you have latest atk4-addons release from github and don't get exception if your php_fileinfo module is not enabled? Strange. if(!function_exists('finfo_open')) should do the trick there. What operating system (OS) you have, what PHP version? Maybe you can find the cause of this bug and provide a solution here or even better in ATK4 Google groups or GitHub?

Comment: This is the commit we're talking about: [5a69383599](https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/commit/5a69383599be84e386f08494208e1a287d762c4c)